# Check time between two columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table, `booking`:

```
id   shop_id    date                start_time      end_time    
1    21         2019-1-13           09:00           10:00           
2    21         2019-1-13           11:00           11:30
```

Now before I a insert record into `booking` table I want to check whether date and time is already booked or not.
How can I do this?

I tried with the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM booking 
WHERE CAST(start_time as date) BETWEEN 
'2012-08-30' AND '2012-08-31';
```

Comment: What are datatypes of those date and time columns?

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain by storing dates and times as a single entity

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'll have separate values for `@date`, `@start_time`, and `@end_time` that you want to check in the table.

To return all overlaps:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM booking b
WHERE @date = b.date AND
      @end_time >= b.start_time AND
      @start_time < b.end_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your table structure it is better to use

```
SELECT * FROM booking 
WHERE CAST(CONCAT(date,' ',start_time)AS timestamp) 
BETWEEN '2012-08-30' AND '2012-08-31';
```

Otherwise it is better to use full timestamp for both start_time and end_time.